# How do I create a program to print titles with certain keywords?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]I am working on a program to read an Excel file and return every title (column 6) that contains a list of keywords. However, I'm having difficulty making the cExcel file indexed. I made the Excel file into a DataFrame, but it still only gives me one column for the header. Any idea how I can fix this problem?

I get results of the info on the Excel[image] file, but the columns headers are combined into 0. I want to read only column 6 and iterate over the titles until it finds a title containing certain keywords.

Comment: You should probably try the more pythonic way to open a csv file using pandas:
`df = pd.read_csv("path_to_your_file")`. If your csv file has a special delimiter (i.e not the standard ",", add a sep=";" argument to that function (of course replace ";" with the relevant separator).

Comment: Why you don't open your CSV file directly by pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
# excludes will be your list of keyword, you keywords should be uniques 

my_excludes = [set(key_word.lower().split()) for key_word in excludes]
match_titles = [e for e in df.Title if any(keywords.issubset(e.lower().split()) for keywords in my_excludes)]
```

Comment: Nothing was returned, but there are titles with the keywords.

Comment: can you give me an example, please ?

Comment: The screenshot above is what I am getting in return.

Comment: are your keywords case sensitive?

Comment: I don;'t believe so.

Comment: @BryanMcCormack check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197802/discussion-between-rusu-ro1-and-bryan-mccormack).